# Drop-down menu button highlighting and hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, beginner

I'm learning JS/jQuery at the moment and have built the following standalone script but I feel that it can probably be improved in some ways?

For example - is there a better way of switching the selected text on the `.dropdown-menu li a` click event rather than needing to replace the entire HTML?

Constructive advice welcome.

EDIT: Added HTML to help with context:

```
<div class="dropdowncontain">
    <button type="button" class="button defaultbutton">Default Value <span class="caret invert"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Katie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Richard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Matthew</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sophie</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Default Value</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>

<div class="dropdowncontain">
    <button type="button" class="button primarybutton">Click Me <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Katie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Richard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Matthew</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sophie</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

So currently the script checks if the user is clicking in a dropdown menu that needs an inverted caret.

```
$(function() {
// Handles initial dropdown click event, if any dropdown menu is visible close it
$('.dropdowncontain').click(function(e){
    if (!$('.dropdown-menu', this).is(':visible')) {
        $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
    }
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).toggle();
    // Stop the bubbling of the event to the document level
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});

// Handles hiding the dropdown menu's when the user clicks elsewhere in the document
$(document).click(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
});

// Handles updating the text in the button and highlighting the selected option
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function(e){
    var parentBtn = $(this).parents('.dropdowncontain').find('.defaultbutton');
    var that = $(this).parents('.dropdowncontain').find('.dropdown-menu li a');
    var selectedText = $(this).text();

        if (that.hasClass('highlightdropdown')){
            that.removeClass('highlightdropdown');
        }

    $(this).addClass('highlightdropdown');  

    // If the containing parent div has a class with 'defaultbutton' add the invert class to the caret
    if (parentBtn.hasClass('defaultbutton')) {
        $(this).parents('.dropdowncontain').find('.button').html(selectedText+' <span class="caret invert"></span>');
    }
    else {
        $(this).parents('.dropdowncontain').find('.button').html(selectedText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
    }
    // Prevent the page jumping to the top when a link with no source is selected
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to swap the text, find the span in the button and toggle the class

```
var isDefault = parentBtn.hasClass('defaultbutton')
$(this).parents('.dropdowncontain').find('.button .caret').toggleClass("invert", isDefault);
```

The context selector is a bad idea

```
$('.dropdown-menu', this)
```

It is slow. Use `find()`

```
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu')
```

Another thing, `$(this)` is used over and over again. That is bad practice. It creates a new jQuery object each time. Store it in a variable and reuse that variable.

```
var myElement = $(this);
myElement.find('.dropdown-menu')...
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice I didn't realise .find() is more perfomant! I am swapping the text in order to update the button's text with what the user selected (increased UX).

Also there is a missing semicolon in isDefault var - thought I'd just let you know!